# Find a closed form of this power series f(x).

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

$$f ( x ) = \sum _ { n = 0 } ^ { + \infty } \frac { ( - 1 ) ^ { n } ( 2 n + 3 ) } { n ! } x ^ { 2 n }$$
Please help to tell me the methods to find a closed form of the infinite series.
Thank beforehand!!

Comment: What have you tried so far? You need to rewrite in in terms of one or more power series you know.

Comment: Please could you add in the question what you've tried?

Comment: And while you try rewriting the sum don't forget to think about where the sums do translate and do not translate into nice functions/terms. For example the geometric sum in standard form only is $1/(1-x)$ for $|x|<1$.

Comment: Ok I will try !

Answer (score 6):

**Hints**:

- $\displaystyle\sum_{n\ge 0}(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n}}{n!}=\mathrm e^{-x^2}$;
- $\displaystyle\sum_{n\ge 0}(-1)^n\frac{(x^{2n})'}{n!}=\frac1x\sum_{n\ge 0}(-1)^n\frac{2n\,x^{2n}}{n!}=\bigl(\mathrm e^{-x^2}\bigr)'$.

Comment: Actually, it's a solution not just hints :)

Comment: I'm sorry, it's only a starting point, and the general idea is  usable in other similar situations.

Comment: And don't forget that the index of the sum could be starting from $1$ when differentiation occurs.

Comment: Thank so much !